# Soluble subgroups of finite classical simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

What do we know about the soluble subgroups of finite classical simple groups (and maybe their automorphism groups)? For example, are their maximal soluble subgroups explicitly known?

Comment: This is, I think, too general a question. For example, *any* subgroup of the simple group $\,A_5\,$ is soluble...! Can you focus a little more on some cases?

Comment: Yes, there are two many soluble subgroups of a finite simple group, so I only ask for some informations rather than a entire list. However, I still expect the determination of maximal soluble subgroups of finite classical simple groups.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "maximal soluble subgroup". There are two possible meanings! The maximal subgroups of the finite classical groups that are soluble are essentially known, although I do not believe that anyone has made a list! Are you familiar with the book by Kleidman and Liebeck, "The subgroup structure of the finite classical groups"? All the information need is in there!

Comment: By "maximal soluble subgroup" I mean the maximal one among the soluble subgroups. If consider the maximal subgroups which are soluble (I prefer to call them "soluble maximal subgroups"), then things are clearer since maximal subgroups in the almost simple class $\mathcal{S}$ are not soluble.

Comment: In that case I think the question is far too difficult, and nothing much is known in general, so you would have to provide more information to be able to make progress!

Comment: There are nontrivial bounds for soluble subgroups of $GL(n,q)$. See for example A. Mann's paper "Soluble subgroups of symmetric and linear groups" and its references. In this paper, the author said a  joint paper with Z. Arad and Y. Segev about the maximal order of soluble subgroups of simple groups is in preparation, but I don't know whether such a papaer is published.